# FOR loop parameter changes its reading position

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I want to loop through **File_1** and check the fourth column. If it's not empty write in **File_2**.

Here is **Files_1**:

```
1;2;3;;;;;;;10
1;2;3;4;;;;;;10
1;2;3;;5;;;;;10
```

Here is my batch file:

```
for /F "delims=; tokens=1-10" %%A in (File_1.txt) do (
    if "%%D" NEQ "" (
        echo hello World %%D >>File_2.txt
    )
)
```

Here is what comes in **File_2**:

```
hello World 10 
hello World 4 
hello World 5
```

How come that it doesn't always read in the fourth column?

The result that I was expecting is:

```
hello World 4
```

How can I manage to have this result?

Comment: Consecutive delimiters are treated as one by `for /F`, so for the first line of your file `Files_1.txt`, the fourth token is `10`, in the next line it is `4`, and in the next one it is `5`; you could replace every `;` by `;_` and precede every line by `_`, so there are no more consecutive delimiters, then after splitting into tokens you can remove the leading `_` from each one...

Answer (score 0):

As your question was answered in the comments, and a solution suggested, I thought I'd provide an alternative:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("File_1.txt") Do Call :Sub "%%A" 
Pause
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
Set "Line=%~1"
Set "i=1"
Set "Token!i!=%Line:;="&Set/A i+=1&Set "Token!i!=%"
If Defined Token4 >>"File_2.txt" Echo Hello World %Token4%
Exit /B
```